# gulp watch and reload jekyll, sass, js

Tags: javascript, jekyll, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I'm trying to build a gulpfile which will watch jekyll/sass/js and sync with a browser. 
The script correctly watches the changes of jekyll, rebuilds and injected all the changes in the browser.

But I can't figure out why it's not syncing sass/js changes, even though they have been watched & regenerated. Any help will be appreciated!

```
/*** gulp.js ***/

var gulp         = require('gulp');
var sass         = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync  = require('browser-sync');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var uglify       = require('gulp-uglify');
var jshint       = require('gulp-jshint');
var header       = require('gulp-header');
var rename       = require('gulp-rename');
var minifyCSS    = require('gulp-minify-css');
var cp           = require('child_process');
var package      = require('./package.json');

var messages        = {
    jekyllBuild: '<span style="color: grey">Running:</span> $ jekyll build'
};

var banner = [
    '/*!\n' +
    ' * <%= package.name %>\n' +
    ' * <%= package.title %>\n' +
    ' * <%= package.url %>\n' +
    ' * @author <%= package.author %>\n' +
    ' * @version <%= package.version %>\n' +
    ' * Copyright ' + new Date().getFullYear() + '. <%= package.license %> licensed.\n' +
    ' */',
    '\n'
].join('');


/**
 * Build the Jekyll Site
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-build', function (done) {
    browserSync.notify(messages.jekyllBuild);
    return cp.spawn('jekyll', ['build'], {stdio: 'inherit'})
        .on('close', done);
});

/**
 * Rebuild Jekyll & do page reload
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-rebuild', ['jekyll-build'], function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});

/**
 * Wait for jekyll-build, then launch the Server
 */
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['css', 'js', 'jekyll-build'], function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'html'
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('css', ['bs-reload'], function () {
    return gulp.src('themes/dental-theme/assets/scss/main.scss')
    .pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
    .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], { cascade: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(header(banner, { package : package }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
});

gulp.task('js',function(){
  gulp.src('themes/dental-theme/assets/js/main.js')
    .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(header(banner, { package : package }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(header(banner, { package : package }))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true, once: true}));
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init(null, {
        server: {
            baseDir: "html"
        }
    });
});
gulp.task('bs-reload', function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});

gulp.task('default', ['css', 'js', 'browser-sync'], function () {
    gulp.watch("themes/dental-theme/assets/scss/*.scss", ['css']);
    gulp.watch("themes/dental-theme/assets/js/*.js", ['js']);
    gulp.watch(['index.html', '_layouts/*.html', '_posts/*'], ['jekyll-rebuild']);
});
```

Comment: Jekyll generates its site in `_site` folder. I do not see in your script where you are copying the output of SASS to _site.

Comment: I have changed this folder to /html on purpose. I have also referenced to the git repo for details https://github.com/Skoks/JekyllBB. Thanks!

Comment: I have never used gulp. I do the similar setup in grunt. See grunt file if its help to you https://github.com/madhur/madhur.github.com/blob/source/Gruntfile.js

Answer (score 5):

Your js and css watch are just regenerating files but not doing a Jekyll build, your html watch does.

Try :

```
gulp.task('default', ['css', 'js', 'browser-sync'], function () {
    gulp.watch("assets/scss/*/*.scss", ['css', 'jekyll-rebuild']);
    gulp.watch("assets/js/*.js", ['js', 'jekyll-rebuild']);
    gulp.watch(['index.html', '_layouts/*.html', '_posts/*'], ['jekyll-rebuild']);
});
```

Edit :

If you don't want to build your Jekyll each time you can just copy you generates assets to destination folder :

```
gulp.task('default', ['css', 'js', 'browser-sync'], function () {
    gulp.watch("assets/scss/*/*.scss", ['css', 'css-to-site']);
    gulp.watch("assets/js/*.js", ['js', 'js-to-site']);
    gulp.watch(['index.html', '_layouts/*.html', '_posts/*'], ['jekyll-rebuild']);
});

gulp.task('js-to-site', function () {
  gulp.src('build/js/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('html/themes/dental-theme/js'));
    browserSync.reload();
});

gulp.task('css-to-site', function () {
  gulp.src('build/css/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('html/themes/dental-theme/css'));
    browserSync.reload();
});
```

Not tested.

Comment: Thanks buddy! It worked, I just had to change the path. Sorry I can't up vote yet, but I definitely will!

Comment: Do I have to rebuild Jekyll every time I change my css/js? Can't I sync only newly generated css/js files in the old, unchanged Jekyll build?

Comment: Not necessary to rebuild each time you change an asset. See my edited answer.